# Why mongodb finds this document ($ne: null for array)

Tags: mongodb

Data:

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
       { _id: 1, item: null },
       { _id: 2 },
       { _id: 3, item: 3 },
       { _id: 4 items: [1, 2, 3] },
       { _id: 5, items: [] }
    ])
```

Query 1:

```
db.inventory.find({ 'item': {$ne: null} })
```

Result 1:

```
{ _id: 3, item: 3 }
```

Query 2:

```
db.inventory.find({ 'items.0': {$ne: null} })
```

Result 2:

```
{ _id: 3, items: [1, 2, 3] },
{ _id: 4, items: [] }
```

Why mongoDB finds this document: { _id: 4, items: [] }?
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$exists: true` instead of `$ne: null`.

[$ne docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) explain:

> $ne selects the documents where the value of the field is not equal to the specified value. **This includes documents that do not contain the field.**

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/ In this example, the query db.inventory.find ({item: null}) displays a document without item. Why does this not work with arrays?

Comment: I don't know, you can ask on https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/.

Comment: Thanks for the link. https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-mongodb-finds-this-document-ne-null-for-array/4420

Answer (score 0):

1. `null` itself a datatype in mongodb. this is why at the `0` index of `items`
   it is searching for a `null` value and not getting it. if you add `null` like 
   `items: [null]` and run the query again you will not see `_id: 4`
2. This is not a bug. this is how Mongo works.
3. In your first result, the key `item` in the object itself does not exist. To satisfy `'item': {$ne: null}` the key itself has to be present in the object. This is how javascript works as well. Check the [JS Code](https://jsfiddle.net/nv7tzwhy/).
4. It also works with arrays. try:  `{'items.0': null}` and `{'items.0': {$ne: null}}`, and you should see the difference.

Comment: But why the first result is missing document ```{ _id: 2 }```.

Comment: docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields In this example, the query db.inventory.find ({item: null}) displays a document without item. Why does this not work with arrays?